# pesquisar um termo em varias tabelas SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

Tenho tabelas com nomes. A tabela "LetraA" contém somente nomes que começam com letra A e assim por diante até a tabela "Letra Z".

Tarefa:

Pesquisar um nome qualquer em todas as tabelas e localizá-lo.

Comment: E o que você já fez ? De forma alguma vou fazer seu dever de casa!

Comment: fiz várias tentativas usando o construtor de consultas do management studio, mas nenhuma tentativa deu certo, por isso pedi a ajuda.

Comment: Mas cadê suas tentativas amigo ? não tem como partir do 'nada' e te ajudar não, mostre o que já tentou, você disse 'várias tentativas' mostre a que mais deu resultado! Clique em Editar e adicione mais informações!

Comment: Seu banco está normalizado?

Comment: acredito que a tarefa é simples. uma vez dando certo com duas tabelas vai dar com todas. Localizar um termo em duas tabelas. As tentativas que eu fiz foi no construtor de consultas, e a cada nova tentativa eu excluo a anterior, por isso estou partindo do zero agora.

Comment: o banco está normalizado. Não existem nomes repetidos nem nomes faltando. Não existem numeros e etc. A tabela LetraA contem apenas nomes que começam com letra A. e assim por diante.

Comment: Sem adicionar suas tentativas ou o que já fez, fica dificil ajudar.

Comment: Se fosse uma tabela apenas acho que assim ficaria bom, mas preciso em todas as tabelas. SELECT * FROM LetraA  WHERE Sobrenome LIKE @Sobrenome + N'%'